# Looking for an in-depth keyboard development tutorial

Tags: android

I know there have been questions here before about keyboard dev, but none of their answers seemed to help me. I'm new to android, but I am an experienced programmer. I'm looking for something that will show me, preferably from scratch, how to write an android keyboard. I want to write something that looks nothing like a standard keyboard (think 8pen). I've looked at [Creating an Input Method](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html) and the [SoftKeyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html) source. The problem with the former is that there's not enough detail - it tells me what the different classes do, but not how to edit them to get what I want. The latter is great for changing what happens when the standard keyboard is used, but it doesn't really have any information about changing the layout.

tl;dr I want to make a keyboard that is essentially just 8 gigantic buttons. Where can I go to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good sample that will get you started: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

From there, everything else is stock Android development.  In-depth documentation can be found here: http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: I did find those sources previously. The problem with the SoftKeyboard was that it showed me how to change the behavior of the buttons, but not how to change the actual look of the keyboard. Because I want my keyboard to look completely different than a normal keyboard, that unfortunately wasn't much help.

Comment: I have the same issue, customer wants a keyboard with the same look and feel of their application

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples for the soft keyboard in the sdk/samples/version. That is googles own modifiable code.  Other than that you can make several keyboard skins using the listed examples or smartkey.